# In list of dataframes, make columns with more than 3 NAs all NA

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

First,
I had a list that including several dataframes like this:

`list:`

`$dataframes1`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| NA | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| NA | NA |
| 1 | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | NA |

`$dataframes2`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

`$dataframes3`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

`$dataframes4`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | 3 |

They all have the same number of rows and variables (i.e., A and B), and there are some NAs in the dataset,
If a variable in the dataframe contain > 3NAs, then the corresponding column will return a NA vector, otherwise remains the same:

e.g.

`$dataframes3`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |

My expected output:

`list:`

`$dataframes1`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |

`$dataframes2`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

`$dataframes3`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |
| NA | 2 |
| NA | 3 |

`$dataframes4`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | 3 |

Is there any way to convert the dataframes in the list without using >2 for loop?
I used 3 for loops to convert and the running speed is very slow...
May be using `lapply` to each dataframe is a good solution? But the code will become difficult to read and debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(dataframes, ~ mutate(
  .x, 
  across(
    everything(),
    ifelse(sum(is.na(.x)) <= 3, .x, NA)
  )
)
```